# Adding CSliderCtrl in CStatusBar in MFC application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to add to `CSliderCtrl` in `CStatusBar`. For this
- Created CSliderCtrl in CMainFrame class
- In `CMainFrame::OnCreate()` added code for creating statusbar and slider bar control as

```
    bStatus =  m_ZoomSlider.Create(
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
    CRect(0, 0, 100, 30),
    &m_StatusBar,
    56666);
```

Things are working fine.

Now I want this slider to be on the right side of the status bar. For this I've added a INDICATOR in the status bar and I am trying to get the rect of this indicator and placing the slider over that rect.

```
CRect rectSlider;
m_StatusBar.GetItemRect(1, &rectSlider);
bStatus =  m_ZoomSlider.Create(
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
    rectSlider,
    &m_StatusBar,
    56666);
```

Here the rectSlider is having negative value, causing the slider to be invisible.

I need to know Is this the correct way for doing this. Any suggestion for advice will be very helpful.

I am using Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using GetRect rather than GetItemRect, I think

Answer (score 0):

The slider control cannot be displayed because its Z-order is not correct. So override on resize to reposition the slider properly. &CWnd::wndTop means placing the window at the top of the Z-order
Firstly, define CSliderCtrl *m_pZoomSlider in MainFrame.h
The following code used the lazy initialization pattern: initialize when required, free the allocated memory when frame is being destroyed.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)
   ...
   ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

   void CMainFrame::SetSliderPosition(int pos)
   {    
        if (!m_pZoomSlider) {
            CRect rectSlider;
            m_wndStatusBar.GetItemRect(1, &rectSlider);
            rectSlider.DeflateRect(1, 1);       // 1 pixel border...
            m_pZoomSlider = new CSliderCtrl();
            m_pZoomSlider->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, rectSlider, &m_wndStatusBar, ID_INDICATOR_SCALE_SLIDER);
            m_pZoomSlider->SetRange(1, 100);
        }

            RECT rc;
            m_wndStatusBar.GetItemRect(pos, &rc);
            // Reposition the slider control correctly!
            m_pZoomSlider->SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndTop, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, 0);

    }

    void CMainFrame::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
    {
        CFrameWnd::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
        SetSliderPosition(1); //index of indicator of status bar
    }

    BOOL CMainFrame::DestroyWindow()
    {   
        if (m_pZoomSlider) {
            m_pZoomSlider->DestroyWindow();
            delete m_pZoomSlider;
        }
        return CFrameWnd::DestroyWindow();
    }
```

Comment: Need an explanation.

Comment: Update answer please.